# Deduced some thing...don't know what to do with it

Tags: geometry

The question reads thus
Find the equation of a circle that touches the x axis at the origin and also touch the line 12x+5y=60

Now,...if i consider the centre of the circle is (a,b)
==>the radius r=|b|
That's all i could deduce
I also thought equating the equations of the cricle and the line would be a good idea to get the point of intersection...but i don't see how it could help m

Could someone help me solve the question and explain the resaoning behind so that i can know what to do next time

In addition...in case we need to find the chord of intersection of two circles are we just supposed to equate them?
Thanks in advanced
Lee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general equation of a circle $x^2 + y^2 + 2gx + 2fy + c = 0$ with center $(-g, -f)$ in this case boils down to $x^2 + y^2 - 2by = 0$ as circle passes through origin ($c=0$) and the center is $(0,b)$ (as you have apparently deduced correctly).
Now use the tangency condition of the line $12x+5y = 60$ to the circle : [perpendicular distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line#Line_defined_by_an_equation) of the center of the circle from the line will be equal to the radius of the circle.

Hence,
$$\frac{|5b - 60|}{13} = b \implies b =  \frac{10}{3}  \ or \frac{-15}{2}$$

As to the second part of your question, yes you are right (if the two circles intersect at two points, the [common chord is equivalent to the radical axis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_chord).), but the condition is that the both the circles' equation should be in the standard form (coefficient of $x^2$ and $y^2$ should be $1$). See [this reference](http://www.math-only-math.com/equation-of-the-common-chord-of-two-circles.html) for a simple proof.

Answer (score 1):

I like Shraddheya Shendre's solution better than what I am giong to show, but this is an alternative.

we have two equations:

$12x + 5y = 60\\
x^2 + y^2 = 2by$

If you find the intersection:

$x = 5 - \frac {5}{12} y\\
(5 - \frac {5}{12} y)^2 + y^2 = 2by$

Yields a quadratic equation.

If the line is tangent to the circle, then the discriminant must equal 0.

$(\frac {25}{144}+1)y^2 - (2b+ \frac {50}{12}) y + 25 = 0$

$(\frac {24b + 50}{12})^2 - 4(\frac {169}{144})(25) = 0\\
576 b^2 + 2400b - 14400=0\\
6b^2 +25b - 150=0$

$b = $$\frac {-25 \pm \sqrt {625 +3600}}{12}
\frac {-25 \pm 65}{12}\\
b = -\frac {15}{2} , \frac {10}{3}$

Comment: I deduced the radius was b

Comment: But why should the x coordinate of the centre be zero

Comment: I don't really understand that

Comment: However i understand your answer in general...although i don't really get the reason why a=0 shraddheya shendre

Comment: a=0 because the circle is tangent to the x-axis at the origin.  That means that if we draw a line through the origin perpendicular to the x-axis $x=0$ it will go through the center of the circle.